# Retrofit2 POST request with body as parameter Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, http-post, retrofit2

I'm new to Kotlin and having trouble to change the existing POST request parameters to body instead. I looked at other answers but none of them have the similar code as mine for the request part. I don't know how to change it just getting a lot of syntax errors. Thanks!

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface PostInterface {
    @POST("signin")
    fun signIn(@Query("email") email: String, @Query("password") password: String): Call<String>
}


class BasicRepo @Inject constructor(val postInterface: PostInterface) {

   fun signIn(email: String, password: String): MutableLiveData<Resource> {
       val status: MutableLiveData<Resource> = MutableLiveData()
       status.value = Resource.loading(null)
       postInterface.signIn(email, password).enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
           override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                 if (response.code() == 200 || response.code() == 201) {
                     // do something
                 } else {
                    // do something
                 }
            }
        }
     }
}

class User constructor(
    email: String,
    password: String
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@POST("signin")
suspend fun signIn(
    @Body body: User,
): ResponseBody
```

Btw, You can use body instead of query params only if your API supports it.
Also, I recommend using a ResultWrapper. [Handling errors with Retrofit and Coroutines in a single place](https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/how-to-handle-errors-with-retrofit-and-coroutines-33e7492a912)

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I'm getting error "Unresolved reference: enqueue". What should I do?

Comment: `enqueue` is a function for this old async solution which is `Call`, the guy in answer used `suspend fun` and Retrofit is adapting to it's usage, now you don't need to "enqueue" the call because coroutine is making it for you, so you just get the `ResponseBody` object back, if you really need to check the status code you can use `retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>` which is a wrapper for this api call where you can check the status code

Comment: @ buszi Thank you. Will it be possible for you to provide the example codes? I'm not sure what to do after the "postInterface.signIn(email, password)" where to call the responseBody.

Comment: You need the pass the model. I.e 
val user = User(email, password)
postInterface.signIn(user)

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. First, in the APIService.kt file add the following @POST annotation:
interface APIService {
    // ...

    @POST("/api/v1/create")
    suspend fun createEmployee(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Response<ResponseBody>

    // ...
}

 2. the POST request will look like this:

private fun callLogIn(type: String, email: String, password: String){

    // Create Retrofit
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(CONST.BASE_URL)
        .build()

    // Create Service
    val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

    // Create JSON using JSONObject
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("login_id", email)
    jsonObject.put("password", password)

    // Convert JSONObject to String
    val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()

 
    val requestBody = jsonObjectString.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // Do the POST request and get response
        val response = service.createEmployee(requestBody)

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                // Convert raw JSON to pretty JSON using GSON library
                val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                val prettyJson = gson.toJson(
                    JsonParser.parseString(
                        response.body()
                            ?.string() 
                    )
                )
                
                Log.d(" JSON :", prettyJson)

            } else {

                Log.e("mytag", response.code().toString())

            }
        }
    }
}
```